# Safari browser flyover is visible even when I'm using Chrome

Tags: bug, status-declined, jobs, mobile-web, mobile-safari

This flyover points at the bookmark icon in Safari, but points at nothing in Chrome.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely not possible, unfortunately - the User Agent strings from Safari and Chrome on iOS are pretty much the same, as they're both using Safari's WebKit rendering engine.

See: [User Agent for Safari browser on iOS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19264114/user-agent-for-safari-browser-on-ios-7)

The flyover only appears the first time you visit the site anyway. I wonder what the clickthrough rate for this is - I struggle to believe a first-time visitor would immediately add any site to their home screen. Maybe we should just get rid of it altogether?

Comment: Especially if I got to that web page from the mobile app anyway. I'm not likely to use both the mobile app and the mobile web site regularly.